# How much Vs whatever

Tags: transatlantic-differences

> Send me *how many books* you have

or

> Send me *whatever book* you have.

My concern  is about quantity of book, so which of these both sentences is correct?

Comment: "how many books" is only valid as part of a question. You could say "however many books", though.

Comment: @JavaLatte Can you please show a sentence using "however". I cannot see how that word improves either phrase in the question.

Comment: @AdrianHHH "send me however many books you have.".

Comment: @Mehjabin In the second sentence, **book** should be plural:  "Send me whatever **books** you have.".

Comment: @JavaLatte Maybe it is a badly phrased question. I read it as asking about the number of books that are held. I think you have interpreted it as asking for books to be sent.

Comment: It would be much clearer to say "How many books do you have?".

Answer (score -1):

Neither.

*"Send me how many books you have"* is close but implies sending the actual books, not their quantity. I would suggest *"Tell me how many books you have"*.

*"Send me whatever book you have"* is also about sending an actual book, but leaves the sender to choose which book to send.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, please show AdrianHHH the courtesy of explaining what you think is wrong with it.